# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XYZ', but when I prtint sys.path I can see the absolute path to folder I want to import

Tags: python, module, path

I want to add all the files and functions from them, they are located in folder 'tabele' which is located in same directory as 'gui' folder where 'konverzijaZaGui.py' is located.
[Tree view of directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc6Ro.png)

Every time when I try to run it says:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabele'

In my code I want to get 'citajIzTabele.py' from 'tabele'

```
import sys
import os
temp = os.path.realpath("../tabele")
temp = os.path.abspath(temp)
sys.path.append(str(temp))

from tabele.citajIzTabele import *
```

When i print sys.path I can see the absolute path of 'tabele' but it still says no module found
I tried relative path to add module but every time it says it is not found

My version of python is 3.10.9 (64bit)

Comment: What is your current working directory when you run this code? ../tabele is relative to that. `sys.path` holds paths to directories that themselves hold the packages and modules you want. Assuming you've got the correct current working directory, you'd want to add ".." (the parent of the directory you want) not ../tabele.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tabele.citajIzTabele import *
```

Will look for *tabele* inside the paths of sys.path but since you added *tabele* itself to sys.path it will look inside that path and does not find it. So either you can add the parent directory of *tabele* to sys.path instead or you can do

```
from citajlzTabele import *
```

Comment: When I try that it just says:  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'citajIzTabele'

Answer (score 0):

If this is a dynamic import, then I have the answer. At the top of the page `import` the modules `sys` and `os`
and type the following code:

```py
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(path)

from folder import file
```

Just an extra note, if you want to just do `import folder` you have to have an `__init__.py` file in there, as that is what it wants to import. With your problem, you can do some string manipulation with the variable `path` to find the folder you're looking for.

Comment: Does '__init__.py' in folder that I want to import has to contain something, because no matter what I do it still says it is not found